# Python interactive after reading sys.stdin

Tags: python, parsing, stdin, python-interactive

I'm trying to write a small graph parser that reads from `stdin` and writes the processed output to `stdout` along the lines of:

```
# parser.py
G = defaultdict(list)
for line in sys.stdin:
    node, neighbor = line.split()
    G[node].append(neighbor)
print(G)
```

I would like to invoke the script with `python -i parser.py < data.txt` and interact with the objects I've created, but the interpreter always exits after the code runs even when I invoke Python with the `-i` option. N.B. The same thing occurs with `ipython`; it even confirms for me that I "really want to exit."

A workaround is to write the code to use a specific file passed in as an argument, but I was wondering if there is a way to make Python not exit the interpreter in the example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The REPL (interactive console) exits when it exhausts standard input.  Ordinarily, standard input is the console, so it only exits when you type ^D or call `quit()` manually.  But if you redirect stdin from a file, stdin will be exhausted when you reach the end of the file.

You can use `argparse` to accept a file on the command line, defaulting to `sys.stdin`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input', type=argparse.FileType(), nargs='?', default=sys.stdin)
args = parser.parse_args()
G = defaultdict(list)
for line in args.input:
    ...
```

Comment: `for line in fileinput.input():`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That's not extensible.  If OP wants to add more arguments in the future, they'll need to rework `fileinput` based solutions.  Such reworking risks breaking backwards compatibility (e.g. because someone wanted to pass a file named `-h`).

Comment: @J.F.: Then you might as well just pass `sys.argv[1]` to `open()` or fall back to `sys.stdin`.  I mean, you aren't going to need the multiple-file capabilities of `fileinput`, right?

Comment: I see. This does feel like the correct way to do it; this lets me test small, manually constructed examples via `python -i parser.py` and on real data via `python -i parser.py file.txt`.

Comment: @Kevin: `fileinput.input()` is the simplest thing that can accept input from files and fall back to `sys.stdin` automatically.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: And, as I explained, that will give you headaches if you ever add another command line switch.  [YAGNI is not a free lunch](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EconomicsOfYagni).

Comment: There is no compatibility issue. I would only pass `-h` as `-- -h` and `fileinput` does not support `--`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: "and fileinput does not support --." -- that's precisely the problem.  If you have an *actual file* named `-h`, you can *only* pass `-h`, because `-- -h` does not work.  Then, you switch to argparse to support `--foo` or whatever, and `-h` breaks.

Comment: yes. It is exactly the point if and when I need it; I'll implement it -- no sooner.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: The person passing arguments at the command line *is not you*.  It's the end user, and they'll do whatever they damn well please, so long as it works.

Comment: @Kevin: If we are talking about end users and backwards compatibility then you should add tests, documentation, etc to your answer. At this point I would use `argparse`

Comment: Can we have a reference to the Python documentation or code that justifies "The REPL (interactive console) exits when it exhausts standard input." ?